# Get datetime from TDateTimePicker

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2010

I am not able to get datetime from TDateTimePicker in C++ builder ide.
I am formatting it to show date and time but it shows only date it's because i think it's `Kind` property is set to `dtkDate`.
is it possible to get date and time from this component ??

```
ShowMessage(deARV->DateTime.FormatString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TDateTimePicker` with its `Kind` property set to `dtkDate` does not have Time associated with it.  If you need both a Date and Time, you have to use two separate `TDateTimePicker` controls, one set to `dtkDate` and the other set to `dtkTime`.  You can then combine their two values together when needed, eg:

```
TDateTime dtDateTime = deARVDate->Date + deARVTime->Time;
ShowMessage(dtDateTime.FormatString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"));
```

I have seen that sometimes this can cause garbage values in the unused portions of the `TDateTime` values, so I prefer to use this instead:

```
TDateTime dtDateTime;
ReplaceDate(dtDateTime, deARVDate->Date);
ReplaceTime(dtDateTime, deARVTime->Time);
ShowMessage(dtDateTime.FormatString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"));
```

Or this:

```
TDateTime dtDateTime = DateOf(deARVDate->Date) + TimeOf(deARVTime->Time);
ShowMessage(dtDateTime.FormatString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"));
```

Comment: ok, thanks Remy. Later, I've found that tms has got `TAdvDateTimePicker` comp which has `dkDateTime` Kind property enabling to extract Date and Time simultaneously using `deARV->DateTime.FormatString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")` we can take datetime value. I think that there is at least 2 solutions available for one problem.